# Determine what script a node process is running

Tags: node.js, windows, pm2

I'm using PM2 on a Windows server to run a bunch of different scripts.  I have found that sometimes when I issue a stop with PM2 it reports the process as stopped but the node process is still running.

I want to be able to determine what script is being run by the node process (as reported by Windows task manager).  If I was binding to a port I could figure it out with net stat but these scripts don't listen on ports, rather they connect to Rabbit MQ.

If I can identify the task in Windows I can forcefully terminate it using task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `tasklist /FI "Imagename eq node"` (or something similar)

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix

Docs for `tasklist`: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx

Related, if your process is listening on a port and you know that number: [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

If you're connected to RabbitMQ your PID will be in the Consumers section of the queue, something like this: `node-amqp-37997-0.5310617093928158` where 37997 is the PID of the process listening.

Comment: This shows me a list of all the node processes but they are all the same, I am unable to determine what script is associated with each node process.  So close :)

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that in my OP.

Comment: Oh, RabbitMQ might be showing the PID of the consumer. See update.